# android - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment not attached to a context

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**What im doing**

Im creating an app, which has a RecyclerView as a menu. Since my app has loacalization, i need to use strings, saved in strings.xml.

**Whats the problem?**

Trying to pass strings value into the parameter causes the app to crash

**What have i tried**

1. using getString() to get the needed value causes the illigalStateException error
2. trying to create a separate string using getString, and using the created string crashes the app
3. context?.getString() crashes the app

**Code:**

**frgSettings.kt**

```
class frgSettings : Fragment() {

    var settingsList = listOf(
        dataItemsSettings(PUT STRING 1 HERE, PUT STRING 2 HERE, R.drawable.ic_colored_color_lens),
        dataItemsSettings(PUT STRING 1 HERE, PUT STRING 2 HERE, R.drawable.ic_colored_view_carousel),
    )

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        retainInstance = true
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rvSettings.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = adapterSettings(settingsList)
        }
    }
}
```

**adapterSettings.kt**

```
class adapterSettings(
    var settingsList: List<dataItemsSettings>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<adapterSettings.SettingsViewHolder>() {

    inner class SettingsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SettingsViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_settings, parent, false)
        return SettingsViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return settingsList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SettingsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.apply {
            rvTitle.text = settingsList[position].stringTitle
            rvDescription.text = settingsList[position].stringDescription
            rvIcon.setImageResource(settingsList[position].itemIcon)
        }
    }
}
```

**dataSettings.kt**

```
data class dataItemsSettings (
    var stringTitle: String,
    var stringDescription: String,
    val itemIcon: Int
)
```

Comment: `companion object {
        fun newInstance(): frgSettings = frgSettings()
    }` terrible idea ... anyway about `settingsList`  make it `lateinit` and set it inside `onAttach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to initialize `settingsList` variable in `onViewCreated` method:

```
//...
lateinit var settingsList: List<dataItemsSettings>

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    settingsList = listOf(
            dataItemsSettings(PUT STRING 1 HERE, PUT STRING 2 HERE, R.drawable.ic_colored_color_lens),
            dataItemsSettings(PUT STRING 1 HERE, PUT STRING 2 HERE, R.drawable.ic_colored_view_carousel),
    )
    rvSettings.apply {
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        adapter = adapterSettings(settingsList)
    }
}

// ...
```